Separation of convex compact set and a subspace
Let $X$ be a real normed space and $C$ be a compact convex set disjoint from a closed subspace $Y$ of $X$.
My claim is that there exists a continuous linear functional $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $Y\subset \ker~f$ and $f(x)>0$ for every $x\in C$.
Reasoning: Since $C$ is compact and $Y$ is closed, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $\mathbf{0}$ such that $(C+V)\cap (Y+V)=\emptyset$ [Rudin Theorem 1.10]
Now, $C+V$ is open and convex, since $C$ is convex. Thus $C+V$ is an open convex set with interior points and disjoint from a closed subspace $Y$. Thus, by the Hahn-Banach separation Theorem, there exists a continuous linear functional $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ f(y)=0 < f(x), \qquad y\in Y, x\in C.$$
Am I correct? Any improvement/comment will be appreciated.
Edit After going through the Brezis Functional Ananlysis Book, I found the following result, known as second geometric form:
Theorem. Let $A \subset E$ and $B \subset E$ be two nonempty convex subsets such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Assume that $A$ is closed and
$B$ is compact. Then there exists a closed hyperplane that strictly separates $A$ and $B$.
In the question, $C$ is compact convex and $Y$ is a closed hyperplane disjoint from $C$. Thus, by applying the stated theorem, we get a closed hyperplane strictly separating $C$ and $Y$. This means there exists a continuous linear functional $f$ and a real number $\lambda$ such that
$$f(x)>\lambda~and~f(y)< \lambda, \qquad x\in C,~y\in Y.$$
However, since $Y$ is a subspace if $f(y)\neq 0$ for any $y\in Y$, then for a suitable choice of $\mu$, we must have $f(\mu y)>\lambda$, a contradiction. Thus, $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in Y$ and $\lambda>0$.
So, we do not actually need the above reasoning, and the conclusion follows from the second geometric form of the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Yes, you are basically proving the strong separation theorem which separates a convex compact set and a closed convex set

I don't know what version of Hanh Banach you are using (there are many), but you need to show that $f(y) = 0$ for all $y$ and that $0 < f(c)$ for all $c$. So, as stated, it looks incomplete to me.

Thank you @copper.hat. Sorry for the late reply. Kindly, check out the edits.

Thank you @EvangelopoulosFoivos for your comment.

Looks fine to me/
